# In UNO, after a successful Wild Draw 4 challenge, what color does play resume on

Tags: uno

Before I am told that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/what-happens-to-the-current-color-when-you-successfully-challenge-a-wild-draw-4), know that that question hasn't been answered, and I cant vote or comment on that due to low reputation.

I have read every single rule book and every interpretation of them available online and I cannot find an answer.

In Uno (or other similar games with a challenge aspect. e.g. UNO flip), when someone successfully challenges a Wild Draw 4 (or WD2 or WDC in flip), does play resume on the colour that was asked before the WD4 was played, or does it change to the colour requested by the person who (illegally) played the WD4.

For example, let's say we have some players including Player A and Player B. It is Player A's turn and the colour is red. Player A has quite a few cards, too many to not assume they will be challenged, but Player B is on UNO, and A knows (or deduces) that their last card is red. Player A plays a WD4, calling yellow, gets challenged, and picks up 4 cards.
Does play continue on yellow or red?

My logical assumption would be red, since Player A's other benefits of their card were forfeited, the colour obviously should have too, but furthermore, the WD4 was played illegally. If A played a red like they should have, play would be red and B would win.

Comment: Could you explain why you believe the possible duplicate _isn't_ answered? The answer from Sparks1738 says "Regardless the outcome of the challenge the Wild Draw 4 stays in play and the game is played normally."

Comment: @PhilipKendall Sparks1738 is wrong about two different aspects, so I don't trust his answer is correct. He also doesn't cite a source.

Comment: You not liking an answer doesn't make the question a non-duplicate. And you not being able to vote or comment doesn't make repeating the question useful to anybody who can, since you are still quite able to read the posts and use or ignore the information as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The color named by the player who (illegally) played the Wild Draw 4:

From the [rules](https://board-games-galore.fandom.com/wiki/Uno):

> Regardless of the outcome (of the challenge), the Wild Draw Four remains on the discard pile and the color of further play is the color named by the player who played the card.

Additional references:

https://github.com/dos-uno/uno-game/blob/master/usual-uno-rules.md

https://www.facebook.com/events/sippin-in-the-mitten/uno-tournament/2721379404647385/

https://github.com/NickCuso/HardlyBot/issues/56

http://gambiter.com/cards/Uno_card_game.html

Comment: Not to be rude, but I don't trust the people over at board-games-galore.fandom. They haven't cited their rules and their 3 references are dodgy.

Their 1st (which seems to be a link to official rules) is a dead link.
Their 2nd is an unofficial fan page that doesn't even mention the case in question.
Their 3rd is https://boardgamegeek.com which has a useful forum for rules, but people there have conflicting answers (e.g. /thread/1610618, /thread/2329607, and /thread/1988608), again with no citations.

Thanks for at least finding an interpretation that mentions this point.

Comment: @TamashiiDane Fair points. But this (seemingly counter-intuitive) interpretation is also seemingly the most widespread. Uno-playing bots, various Uno tournaments, and so on: they all use this rule if any is specified. (Though the people using the more intuitive ruling may perhaps be less likely to specify it explicitly, since it is "obvious").